# how to add image with text in qlistwidget pyqt4 python?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistwidget

How to add image/icon with text in a qlistwidget in pyqt4 python? I want to add an icon with text just like a chat system. thanks

Comment: [`QListWidgetItem`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#QListWidgetItem-3)s can have icons. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to add icon before or after the text. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried this right now and it works, supposing you have a file named tick.png in the same folder as this script.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog, QListWidgetItem, QListWidget, QIcon

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QDialog()

    list = QListWidget( window )

    itm = QListWidgetItem( "Tick" );
    itm.setIcon(QIcon(r"tick.png"));
    list.addItem(itm);

    window.show( )
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The chat-like-icon system may be different from this, but right now I don't see a way to have a QListWidgetItem with multiple smileys and text.

You may think of smileys as a particular case of a QListWidgetItem where the text is blank and only the icon is present.

Another solution is using a read-only QTextEdit as chatboard and have the user typing its text + icon + text (etc.) in a separate editable QTextEdit. Then, when he presses the send button, append everything he typed to the read-only QTextEdit.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QDialog, QListWidgetItem, QListWidget, QIcon, QTextEdit, QTextDocumentFragment

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QDialog()

    list = QListWidget( window )

    textEditor = QTextEdit( window );
    textEditor.setReadOnly( True )
    tick_icon = QTextDocumentFragment.fromHtml(r"<img src='tick.png'>");

    textEditor.insertPlainText ( " ValiumKnight writes: " )
    textEditor.textCursor().insertFragment(tick_icon);
    textEditor.insertPlainText ( " Hello World " )
    textEditor.textCursor().insertFragment(tick_icon);
    textEditor.textCursor().insertFragment(tick_icon);
    textEditor.textCursor().insertFragment(tick_icon);

    window.show( )
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Bye!

Comment: My only problem now is how to separate icons form text. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Can you give me an example of the problem you have now? I may try to give you some further help.

Comment: I've use the text editor. For example i have message "thanks :)". Since inserting text and icon is separate function. How will i know if :) will be inserted as icon or text. Or how do i parse the message to know that its for the insert icon or text function. Thanks @ValiumKnight